# 2019 SPECS FOR RUNNING GETH FULL NODE

Tags: go-ethereum

What are the specs for running an ethereum full node in Jan 2019? No fast flags as eth.blocknumber and some other methods needed. PLEASE NEED OFFICIAL ANSWER Thank you!

I have a very powerful machine but its still having problems. 6 cpus, 18gb mem
SSD: 450 GB (42%used) but the node syncs once and then starts lagging behind...

Comment: First `eth.blockNumber` does work in fast mode, but your node has to finish syncing. Your setup appears to be good. Sometimes the syncing appears to stop close to the most recent block but if you wait it should complete. Do you have logs to examine what is happening? Ethereum is quite intensive reading/writing to disk, make sure other processes are not using all the disk io since it can slow geth syncing.

Comment: hashimoto algorithm requires only RAM SPEC(>2GB).

Comment: What command line are you using to launch geth?

Answer (score 2):

A Geth node with Fast sync is around 130GB ([source](https://etherscan.io/chart2/chaindatasizefast)). However, according to [this article](https://dev.to/5chdn/the-ethereum-blockchain-size-will-not-exceed-1tb-anytime-soon-58a), once Geth is done with Fast sync, it switches to full (archive) sync. With a Parity Archive node approaching 2TB ([source](http://whataboutarchivenodes.5chdn.co/)) you can expect at least that much in disk-space (SSD with high i/o). Running a stable node is a challenge, so you may want to look into a service like [QuikNode](https://quiknode.io/) (cloud node-as-a-service), which offers Archive nodes w/ full chain data since genesis block.

Comment: -1 for not disclosing an affiliation with QuikNode

Answer (score 2):

I started a `fastsync` `full` node yesterday with `geth`.

It's currently `100` blocks behind and and several thousand states behind.

`161 GB` as of now (March 15, 2019) 24 hours after starting the node.

I've read else where it takes another day or two to sync the states.

Specs as follows:

- Ubuntu 18.04 via HyperV
- 8GB RAM - DDR4
- 4x CPU cores (AMD Ryzen 1700)
- 40GB SSD (boot)
- 2TB SSD (eth node storage)
- 400 Mbs / 20 Mbs cable internet

In visual monitoring of system resources, I never went above 300% (400% being the max for 4 cores) CPU utilization. And I usually retained 33% or less on RAM utilization.

Edit - I did see some RAM spikes just past 50%

Comment: Completed sync in 30 hours and 4o minutes